# ASP.NET enable dot sign web.config

Tags: asp.net, ssl, web-config

I need to redirect www.domain.com/.well-known/pki-validation/godaddy.html from my webpage to get SSL Certificate from godaddy. but when im given the file path from the web.config file to redirect to it suddenly my site not working. the reason is dot sign.

Please can you guys help me to figure this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Give proper url with http:\\


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string url= WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"].ToString();

       Response.Redirect(url);
    }


  <appSettings>
    <add key="url" value="your url""/>
    <add key="SiteName" value="New York Times"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: but "www.domain.com/.well-known/pki-validation/godaddy.html" this path shuld be like this. godaddy mention about that. thats the case :(

Comment: Exactly what error you are getting. Please share screen shot.